# How to use the reduce function on array of custom Object in Swift

Tags: functional-programming, swift

Considering a Swift Object `class Sheep` having a simple property `var position: CGRect`

```
class Sheep {
    var position: CGRect

    init() {
        position = CGRectZero
    }
}
```

In an array of Sheep `Array<Sheep>` How can I get the `Sheep` with the highest `position.origin.y`?

I tried the following but got an `error: could not find member y`

```
func firstSheep(sheeps: Array<Sheep>) -> Sheep
{
     return sheeps.reduce(sheeps[0]) {max($0.position.origin.y, $1.position.origin.y)}
}
```

All classes import

```
import Foundation
import QuartzCore
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max` is going to return a CGFloat (whichever y is greater). Instead you want to return the sheep that has the highest y value:

```
return sheeps.reduce(sheeps[0]) {
    ($0.position.origin.y > $1.position.origin.y) ? $0 : $1
}
```

But be careful because this method will throw a runtime error if `sheeps` is nil. I would make the return value optional and do the following:

```
func firstSheep(sheeps: [Sheep]) -> Sheep?
{
    let initial : Sheep? = nil
    return sheeps.reduce(initial) {
        if !$0 {
            return $1
        }
        return ($0!.position.origin.y > $1.position.origin.y) ? $0 : $1
    }
}
```

You need to setup initial as a separate variable to massage the generic in `reduce` to be correct.

Comment: i get however the error: Type '($T14, $T18)' does not conform to protocol 'LogicValue'

Comment: @NicolasManzini are you sure you copied exactly? I ran this code in a playground just fine

Comment: indeed NO :) i didn't copy exactly I made a mistake somewhere

Comment: @NicolasManzini Also be careful that this function will throw a runtime error if `sheeps` does not contain at least one sheep

Comment: yes i was trying to figure out how I could nil the default parameter and return a Sheep? var

Comment: @NicolasManzini I updated my answer to show how you could do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55678/discussion-between-nicolas-manzini-and-drewag).